# The plugin admob_flutter uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, admob

when i put `admob_flutter: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.1` in pubspec, and type on cmd flutter pub get this error occurs!

The plugin `admob_flutter` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of
Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for latest flutter updates. so you can't do anything. Please use other package or wait till fix the problem by package developer because this error is produced after flutter version 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

I have downgraded my flutter version by command `flutter downgrade` and it shows an option of a downgraded flutter version and it resolves my error.

Comment: what is the number of your  flutter version ?

Comment: Flutter 2.3.0-16.0.pre

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading flutter worked for me.